# Creating a cache of generic objects

Tags: java, generics, caching

I need to create a Java cache of generic objects.  I'm trying to do the following but this will not compile.

```
public class Example<T> {

  public static class ExampleCache {
    private Map<String, Example<?>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public <T> Example<T> getExample(String name) {
      return cache.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new Example<T>());
    }
  }
}
```

The line with cache.computeIfAbsent generates the error

```
"Error:(16, 35) java: incompatible types: Example<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to Example<T>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because type `T` is not compatible with the wildcard `?`. How can the compiler know that the `Example<T>` would be received from the map of values `Example<?>`? You have to use casting or better apply the type to the static class as well:

```
public class Example<T> {

    public static class ExampleCache<T> {

        private Map<String, Example<T>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        public Example<T> getExample(String name) {
            return cache.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new Example<>());
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't include the type to the `ExampleCache`, the error would be thrown:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T

This will work only if the `ExampleCache` is not `static` but then the instance of a `ExampleCache` will be fixed to an instance of `Example<T>`. For more info, read [Java generics with class and nested static interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5211890/3764965).

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do is not type safe.
You could cast `?` to `T` but it would be not type safe :

```
return (Example<T>) cache.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new Example<T>());
```

You want that the clients of `getExample()` decide the generic type of the returned `Exemple` instance.
Suppose you added as entry `"hello"-"Example<String>"` and that the client invokes `getExample()` in this way : `Example<Integer> example : getExample("hello");`, he/she would have an incorrect generic type and it could provoke some inconsistency/exceptions at runtime.

In fact the `ExampleCache` is not consistent about the generic types that it has as input/output.
So either replace the wildcard by `T` to define an `ExampleCache` of a specific type or use only `Example<?>` in the cache as in the client class or still don't use generics for the `Example` class.