# Called method of inner generic class doesn't recognize the generic type

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes, java-11

I struggle with the following inner class "inheriting" the generic parameter `T` from the outer class. The following lines are erroneous:

```
String string = "string";
new OuterClass<>()
    .inner(string)
    .call(s -> s.length());       // Cannot resolve method 'length' in 'Object'
```

Minimal and reproducible example of these classes:

```
public class OuterClass<T> {

    public InnerClass<T> inner(T object) {
        return new InnerClass<>(object);
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    public static final class InnerClass<U> {

        U object;

        public final void call(Consumer<U> consumer) {
            consumer.accept(object);
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this happen? How am I supposed to specify the generic parameter through the creation of the inner class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get an inner class to inherit enclosing class' generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765211/how-do-i-get-an-inner-class-to-inherit-enclosing-class-generic-type), [Java generics with class and nested static interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211890/java-generics-with-class-and-nested-static-interface)? (Not the one to downvote!)

Comment: Java type resolution is not strong enough to deduce the required type in this case. Use `OuterClass<String>()` instead of `OuterClass<>()`.

Comment: I have edited the question. I have tried to replace `T` with `U` previously, yet the result remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, this is because inference of type in the `<>` does not take into account the subsequent methods that you chain.

For example, this creates an `ArrayList<Object>`:

```
new ArrayList<>().add("");
```

If I insert the word `String` inside the `<>`, IntelliJ will not complain that the word `String` is redundant.

Similarly, this produces an error:

```
OuterClass<String>.InnerClass i = new OuterClass<>().inner(string);
```

Because the right hand side produces a `OuterClass<Object>.Inner`, while the left hand side is a `OuterClass<String>.InnerClass`.

To fix this, you need to specify the generic parameter:

```
new OuterClass<String>()
    .inner(string)
    .call(s -> s.length());
```

Regarding your edit, the edited `inner` method still depends on the generic type of `Outer`, which cannot be inferred correctly.

You can make the `Inner` object created *not* depend on the generic type of `Outer` by adding another generic parameter:

```
public <U> InnerClass<U> inner(U object) {
    return new InnerClass<>(object);
}
```

Comment: Right, my mistake. I have completely forgotten this issue as I started to use inner classes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sweeper the last suggestion leaves the `T` in `OuterClass` unused in the current context. I would consider a cleaner way to represent the intended code would be         `OuterClass<String> outerClass = new OuterClass<>();
        OuterClass.InnerClass<String> innerClass = outerClass.inner(string);
        innerClass.call(String::length);`

Comment: @Naman Yeah. Without context, we don't know what these types represent. They might be used somewhere else. And after the OP's edit, it seems like the operation `new OuterClass<>().inner(string).call(...)` doesn't need to depend on `T` anymore, because OP introduced `U`.

Comment: @Naman I thought OP's intention was to chain methods. If you were to write the operation in separate statements. then no modification to the classes is needed, right?

Comment: If you mean the code before the edit, then `OuterClass<String> outerClass = new OuterClass<>();        outerClass.inner(string).call(String::length);` would have been sufficient to represent the chain we are talking about. The question mislead on an awkward time with an acceptance of a half-written answer. Only @Nikolas can tell what the requirement was and is.